# About one line in an implementation of MD5

Tags: c, md5

I'm confused by one line of code in an [implementation of MD5](https://openwall.info/wiki/people/solar/software/public-domain-source-code/md5),

```
void MD5_Update(MD5_CTX *ctx, const void *data, unsigned long size)
{
    MD5_u32plus saved_lo;
    unsigned long used, available;

    saved_lo = ctx->lo;
    if ((ctx->lo = (saved_lo + size) & 0x1fffffff) < saved_lo)
        ctx->hi++;
    ctx->hi += size >> 29;

    used = saved_lo & 0x3f;

    if (used)
    {
        available = 64 - used;

        if (size < available)
        {
            memcpy(&ctx->buffer[used], data, size);
            return;
        }

        memcpy(&ctx->buffer[used], data, available);
        data = (const unsigned char *)data + available;
        size -= available;
        body(ctx, ctx->buffer, 64);
    }

    if (size >= 64)
    {
        data = body(ctx, data, size & ~(unsigned long)0x3f);
        size &= 0x3f;
    }

    memcpy(ctx->buffer, data, size);
}
```

The question line is `if ((ctx->lo = (saved_lo + size) & 0x1fffffff) < saved_lo)`, it seems the 'size' counts bytes, but the 'ctx->lo' and 'saved_lo' count bits. Why add them together? There are also some similar codes in Github, and also some projects use these code. So anyone can give some explanation?

Comment: Sorry, but you're asking us to guess the intent of the author, which makes really bad questions here. Firstly, try to find out when the line was written, by whom and with what comment it was checked in. Then, play around with it by just modifying it and looking at the outputs.

Comment: Because MD5 is so well known. So I think must someone can give a answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remarks about "bit counters" are likely misleading - `ctx->hi` and `ctx->lo` count bytes, just like `size` does.

You correctly notice that you're just adding `size` (bytes) to `ctx->lo` (and then checking for overflow/propagating overflow into `ctx->hi`). The overflow check is pretty simple - `lo` is used as a 29-bit integer, and if the result after adding/masking is less than the original value, then overflow occurred.

The checks around `used` are also evidence for `ctx->lo` and `ctx->hi` being byte counters -- `body` processes data 64 *bytes* at a time, and the `lo` counter is ANDed with `0x3F` (i.e. 63).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I confused it with other implementations which count bits with 'lo' and 'hi'.